# Data from the active worksheet is being extracted when trying to reference a different worksheet

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to retrieve data from another worksheet in my workbook, but when i execute the code, the cell references are working, but they are retrieving from the current worksheet, not the other one.

I have tried using the name of the worksheet, as well as "Sheet7" (as seen below), one just grabs the data from the active worksheet and the other produces a runtime error 9.

```
  While found = False
      If Worksheets("Sheet7").Range("B" + CStr(i)).Value = cmbSA.Value Then
          numBuilt = Worksheets("Sheet7").Range("C" + CStr(i + 1)).Value
          found = True
      Else
          i = i + 1
      End If
  Wend
```

I expect the if statement to be true when i = 4, but it is only true when i=10, which is the required value, only its from the active worksheet.

Comment: Just a note: don't use the `+` to concatenate, use `&`. Also the `Cstr` is redundant. Also I'm not sure a loop is necessary here, you may be able to use `Range.Find` and `Offset`. What is `cmbSA.Value` in this case?

Comment: cmbSA.Value is just a string from a combo box. Could you show what you mean by using the Range.Find?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A loop is overkill here, and could cause issues. What if `cmbSA.value` is never found? Also, `While...Wend` is deprecated.

It sounds like all you need is `Range.Find`.

As an example:

```
Dim foundCell as Range
Set foundCell = Worksheets("Sheet7").Range("B:B").Find(What:=cmbSA.Value, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)

If Not foundCell is Nothing Then
    numBuilt = foundCell.Offset(1, 1).Value
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

I know you've asked a VBA question and might want to do it in VBA for other reasons, but there is a fairly simple formula to get this with no code.

Use MATCH to find your value and OFFSET to get it. You can do this from another sheet. I won't explain further in case you specifically don't want to use formulae.

Comment: Actually it's just a straight VLOOKUP.

Comment: =VLOOKUP(cmbSA.value,Sheet7!B:C,2,0)

Comment: Note the `i+1` in OP's VBA
. VLOOKUP won't work. INDEX/MATCH, increasing the result of MATCH by 1, would. OFFSET is volatile and not recommended.

Comment: Good point about the i+1, so you would use MATCH and then I'd use OFFSET but you can use INDEX if you prefer.

Comment: OFFSET is volatile. No need for it. From Microsoft directly, referring to volatile functions, ["Use them sparingly"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/excel/excel-recalculation) :)

Comment: I would definitely use it sparingly. However as my ranges tend to be only definable using INDIRECT, it really doesn't matter. But none of this is relevant to the OP. (OP, just use MATCH and INDEX. Or VBA.)

Comment: So all in one: =INDEX(Sheet7!B:C, MATCH(cmbSA.value, Sheet7!B:B, 0)+1, 2)